# Automating the splitting of a large mp3 file with FFmpeg into multiple files in different time points provided in a text file

Tags: ffmpeg, split, mp3

I have a large mp3 file; I want to split it into 480 mp3 files in different time points. I want to know if there is an easy way to do it other than splitting it one by one. Can I provide the different splitting times in a text file and just execute one command in FFmpeg?

Comment: Use the [segment](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer with the `-segment_times` option.

Comment: Write a shell script to read the text file, call `ffmpeg` to execute the command with the right arguments.

Comment: Can you write an example of the command please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this script

```
#! /bin/bash
x="00:00:00"
z=0
filename=$(basename -- "$2")
ext="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
initcmd="ffmpeg  -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel error -i $2"
while read y
do
initcmd+=" -ss $x -to $y -c copy $filename$z.$ext"
let "z=z+1"
x=$y 
done < $1
$initcmd
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x`

And make your time configuration file like this, timestamps separated by space.

```
00:02:30 
00:05:40
```

Remember to press enter after the last entry.

And then the syntax is

```
./splitter.sh ./time ./Big_Buck_Bunny.mp4
```

It will result two files `1.mp4` and `2.mp4`, first one is from 00:00:00 to 00:02:30, second one from 00:02:30 to 00:05:40. If you want to make rest the file in a output, run this command

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -sexagesimal -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 Big_Buck_Bunny.mp4 >> ./time
```

(This gets the length of the file and add to your time config)

**Explanation**

Line 2: set initial start time
Line 3: set output file name number
Line 4, 5 and 6: set extension (From a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash#965072))
line 7 : a string with initial parameter
while loop: reads line by line (From [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642191/read-line-by-line-in-bash-script#464221))
Line ffmpeg: `-nostdin` stops ffmpeg from eating first characters
`-hide_banner -loglevel panic` suppress ffmpeg messages
`-i` set input file name
Line initcmd+=: adds output name and parameter
`-ss` start time
`-to` end time
`-c copy` use same codec as input, no quality loss and fastest.
line 10:  increment file name number (From [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash#385532) Post)
line 11: set new start point

Edit:

1. Now it can read line separated file. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533441/why-reading-line-by-line-and-feeding-ffmpeg-removes-leading-character-gradually)
2. Instead of repeatedly calling ffmpeg, do everything in last line with [multiple output](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs)

Comment: Interesting. Is this accurate down to MPEG frames? So far, I have only used shnsplit.

Comment: @Hermann If I understand your question, it can be set by position of `-ss` relative to `-i`. See [ffmpeg doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted, thank you so much.

Comment: @YucefBerus Then you may mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried it last night and it worked wonderfully, then today i tried it with different timestamps and it keeps telling me Invalid duration specification for to: 00:06:02 or other timestamps

Comment: @YucefBerus, you may post your time config file, the file with time stamps, there may be formating in that error. Also check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video/141343#141343) if there's anything wrong.

Comment: Here is my time config file [time](https://pastebin.com/WQXbhUma) @IbnFulan

Comment: @YucefBerus just ran . No error. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Add `echo $x $y` at the beginning of while loop (After 9th line) to see what it's actually feeding.

Comment: This is what give me after executing the command [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/DOBk4Dn) @IbnFulan

Comment: There supposed to be two columns, like [this](https://imgur.com/yfkA1uX). For some reason your `x` is not present , the variables aren't swaped at line 12.

Comment: Well this is just odd, i switched to Linux (KDE Neon) and recreated the script and the time config file using Visual Code  and it worked fine, i guess it had something to do with Windows 10 and how time file is created with the spacing between the time stamps, i'll just work on Linux, sorry for taking your time. @IbnFulan

Comment: I wanted to ask you the same question, what you've used to write the file. In Windows, setting text editor to Unix like ending (LF) may correct this. Windows use CRLF line ending

Comment: Okey, i'll try that, thanks. @IbnFulan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127990/discussion-between-ibn-fulan-and-yucefberus).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Lossless Cut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) but it is a GUI application. You can export several output files at once.